# having trouble looping sql insert with php

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to php and sql and what im trying to achieve is loop an sql insert into the same column with different values form another table with different columns i am able to do it without loop but i cant seem to get it to work with this loop. any help would be greatly appreciated.

edited.

i want to insert the sum values of table tblplyrbetlisttemp to  tblcollplasada depending if $vresults  == 'SK-WALA' or $vresults  == 'SK-MERON' the outcome should insert 3 rows with fldM7 fldW7 and  fldM7price or  fldW7price depending on $vresults value.

table structure listed below

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| tblplyrbetlisttemp                      |
+-----------------------------------------+
| fldM7price | fldW7price | fldM7 | fldW7 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                             tblcollplasada                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fldtag | fldtranno | fldfightno | fldtrandate | fldusrcd | fldwinner | fldpercomm | fldSK | fldarenaid |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
```

for example $vresults is equals to 'SK-WALA' and table tblplyrbetlisttemp has values  fldM7=5 fldW7=5 fldW7price=500

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|            tblplyrbetlisttemp           |
+-----------------------------------------+
| fldM7price | fldW7price | fldM7 | fldW7 |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
|     500    |            |   5   |       |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
|            |     500    |       |   5   |
+------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

output should be

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                             tblcollplasada                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fldtag | fldtranno | fldfightno | fldtrandate | fldusrcd | fldwinner | fldpercomm | fldSK | fldarenaid |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
|        |           |            |             |          | SK-WALA   |            | 500   |            |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
|        |           |            |             |          | SK-WALA   |            | 5     |            |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
|        |           |            |             |          | SK-WALA   |            | 5     |            |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+
```

code:

```
function CollectComm ($vresults) {
global $iSqlConnDb;global $varfightno;global $percomm;global $comm ;global $vtagid;global $ActvARenId;

     if ($vresults  == 'SK-WALA') { $win = 'W';$lose = 'M';  } 
     if ($vresults  == 'SK-MERON') { $win = 'M';$lose = 'W';  } 

    $winOdd =array('fld' . $win . '7price','fld' . $win . '7','fld' . $lose .'7');

    $query_rscoll = "select  distinct(fldusrcd) as vuser from tblplyrbetlisttemp where fldarenaid='$ActvARenId'";
    $rscoll = mysql_query($query_rscoll, $iSqlConnDb) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rscoll = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscoll);
    $totalRows_rscoll = mysql_num_rows($rscoll);
    if ($totalRows_rscoll > 0) {

         do { 
          $vhave = false;
          $varuserid  = $row_rscoll['vuser'];
          $vtrandate = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($winOdd); $i++) { 
                $OC[$i] ='';
                $varodd =  $winOdd[$i];

                $rsTotcomm = mysql_query("select SUM($varodd) as totodd FROM tblplyrbetlisttemp where  fldarenaid='$ActvARenId' and fldusrcd='$varuserid'");    
                $vcomm=mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTotcomm);

                if ($vcomm['totodd'] > 0 || ) {
                    $vhave = true;

                       $OC[$i] =$comm * $vcomm['totodd'] ;

                }       



                if ($vhave == true) {
                    $vtranno =  AutoIDArena('tblcollplasada','fldtranno',$ActvARenId);
                    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tblcollplasada(fldtag,fldtranno,fldfightno,fldtrandate,fldusrcd,fldwinner,fldpercomm,fldSK,fldarenaid)  
                    VALUES(" . $vtagid .  ","  .  $vtranno . ","  .$varfightno . ",'" . $vtrandate . "','" . $varuserid . "','" .  $vresults . "','" . $percomm . "','" . $OC[$i] . "','" . $ActvARenId . "')";
                    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $iSqlConnDb) or die(mysql_error());
                }

            }

     } 

     while ($row_rscoll = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscoll)); } 

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your tables' strucutre, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data?

Comment: edited the above code and added the important table structure